# Calculation Of tax with different product taxes rates php sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have following table "**Cart**" & contains the following columns in mysql:

CartID, ProductID, ProductPrice, ProductTax (%), ProductQty

ProductTax is in Percentage but value stored as number/int.

How do i calculate total tax of all products in the cart.

So each product must use its own "ProductTax" Rate ie. in %tage .

(1) example contain 1 product in cart.
ProductPrice: 200 & ProductTax 18%. & ProductQTY:1

So "**totaltax**" here is: 36.

(2) example contains 2 products in cart

1- ProductPrice: 300 & ProductTax 18% & ProductQTY: 2
2- ProductPrice: 400 & ProductTax 20% & ProductQTY: 1

So for above example "**totaltax**" is : 108+80= 188

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Calculate them while you loop through the products and total them at the end... What do you have so far?

Comment: @VA79  I have added example in question.

Comment: SELECT SUM((ProductPrice * ProductQty)* ProductTax/100) AS value_sum FROM Carts  . This solves it!

Comment: I mean what do you have in code so far?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

To calculate total tax of all products in the cart:

```
SELECT SUM((ProductPrice * ProductQty)* ProductTax/100) AS value_sum
FROM Cart
```

This solves it! – Webgen 10 secs ago   edit